# Representation of 3D polytope in 2D

Tags: python, r, plot

I am struggling with polytope representation.
I have a set of vertices (in 3D) defining a convex polytope. And I want to plot it.
I can easily represent the whole polytope in 3D or its projection in 2D. But I cannot find a packages (in R or Python) to represent it in 2D with the third component represented by a color on the plot.
For instance, if I have such a set of vertices :

```
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1.]])
```

In 3D you get :
[image: Polytop plot generated by plotly]

And What I would like to have is the upper envelop in the Z axis which should look like something like this:
[image: Contour plot generated with plotly]

(minus the contours of course...). If you have any idea how to solve this representation issue I am all ears!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, reshape the array and then use your favourite package to plot, eg. seaborn or matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = [[0., 0., 0.],
     [1., 0., 0.],
     [0., 1., 0.],
     [1., 1., 0.],
     [0., 0., 1.],
     [1., 0., 1.]]

data = np.asarray(m).reshape(3,6)[::-1]
sns.heatmap(data, cmap = 'jet')
#plt.imshow(data)
plt.xlabel('level 1')
plt.ylabel('level 2')
```

[image]

Maybe this can help!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not sure it helps. The plot you made has nothing to do with the projection of the polytope, and in this example I choose a simple one, but there is no reason for the polytope to have a squared projection. Moreover, I want to use the fact that it is a polytope and not a simple set of vertices.